# Test an LCD for missing segments without looking at the screen?

Tags: measurement, lcd, test, optoelectronics, test-equipment

I have a product with an LCD screen that sometimes fails with missing segments.
I will test the product for a long time to replicate the failure.
I will test many at once.
I don't want to sit watching the displays with my eyeballs.
I write computer programs to control lab test equipment.
I can make the screen display arbitrary patterns at will.
Is there an instrument that can monitor whether a segment is out while I'm not looking?
Thanks.

Comment: LCD like these black/transparent ones?

Comment: *"Is there an instrument that can monitor whether a segment is out while I'm not looking?"*  Yes.  Look up something called a "camera".

Comment: [It's dangerous to go alone! Take this.](http://opencv.org/)

Comment: Yep, there are devices that can monitor screens. Its called a camera

Comment: If you want you can write some software to analyze the images

Answer (score 1):

You could produce an automated display monitor using OpenCV, and any computer you have sitting around which can handle the processing load. The trick is the camera. It needs to be high resolution enough to resolve whatever error you're looking for.

In professional display testing environments very high resolution and finely calibrated cameras called colorimeters are used to test displays and evaluate their performance in conjunction with other tools such as spectrophotometers and other tools.

For your application, make sure whatever camera you use can clearly resolve the segments. You can write a program using OpenCV to detect and log the error. Depending on the resolution you're capturing and how fast you need to process a very small computer like a raspberry pi can handle the load.

Comment: It will be hard to detect the contrast of the segments on camera. You will need to setup a evenly lit environment as well.